# Excel VBA ADO to workbook syntax - multiple conditions

Tags: excel, vba, ado

I'm querying another Excel workbook via ADO connection. In several parts, I need to use multiple conditions, but I can't seem to figure out the syntax. Can anyone point out a fix to my sql string?:

SELECT FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE Date = '10/05/2017' AND Group = 3

It seems to work fine when I only use one condition, but not multiple. Thanks!

[edit] The error I'm getting says "Syntax error (missing operator in query expression 'Date = '10/05/2017' AND'."

Comment: Square brackets aren't normally a requirement, but could be around `Date` - that's probably a reserved word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem, just have to add square brackets around field names when multiple conditions. Struggling with the date a bit, but I'll get that down.